# How do I get Bootstrap Tour to work with a jQuery dialog?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-dialog

Basically I can get [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) working with the most basic example, but when targeting an element in a jQuery dialog the highlight covers up the element.

```
var t = new Tour({
    backdrop: true
});

t.addStep({
    element: "#content",
    title: "Title",
    content: "Content"
});

t.start();
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJPGL/1/) of what I mean.

[image: Bootstrap Tour with a jQuery Dialog]

The highlight element should be behind the targeted element so that the text is still visible.

I think the issue is the z-index of the elements. It should be dialog -> highlight -> element, but instead it looks like it's dialog -> element -> highlight.

The z-index of the dialog is 100, the highlight is 1010 and the element is 1011, which I believe should be correct.

I can make it work by explicitly removing the z-index on the `.ui-front` jQuery UI class, but that doesn't seem like the best solution.

Any ideas why the default styling doesn't work if the z-index's are correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem rests in the fact that the [*jQuery-UI Dialog*](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) has created a new stacking context and so changes to the `z-index` of the `#content` element will only show up relative to it's current stacking context.

For proof, add the following css, and you'll still see the `#content` div display **above**  the dialog, which has a `z-index` of `100`. --> i.e. **Z-indexes are not absolute!** ... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/v3QCW/1/)

```css
#content { z-index: 0 !important; }
```

---

From [**What No One Told You About Z-Index**](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/):

> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order.  That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a z-index of a billion!
>
> New stacking contexts can be formed on an element in one of three ways:
>
> - When an element is the root element of a document (the  element)
> - When an element has a position value other than static and a z-index value other than auto
> - When an element has an opacity value less than 1

---

The problem is [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) doesn't really have a good way of identifying this.  When they start a tour on an element, they apply:

- A full screen black `tour-backdrop` with a z-index of `1009`,
- A white `tour-step-background` behind the object with a z-index of `1010`
- and apply a z-index to the current tour element of `1011`

...but the last `z-index` has no effect since our object is already in a stacking context.  It is just positioned higher than any of the other elements within that stack (which it already was).  Incidentally, that's why removing the `z-index` from `ui-front` results in the proper appearance because it frees the element from its current stack.

---

Here's what Bootstrap Tours **should** be doing, and we'll do manually with DOM manipulation.

The problem is that they are trying to position the elements relative to one another with z-indexes, but anytime the tour object is in a stacking context different from the `.tour-step-background` and `.tour-backdrop`, this will fail.

## Solution?  Place the elements you're generating inside the same stacking context!

Here's a simplified markup tree

- Body

  - Tour background **(normally goes here)**
  - New stacking context

    - Tour object
    - Tour background **(should go here)**

To override this, we'll plugin to the tours `onShown` method and move the backdrops ourselves:

In **JavaScript**, when creating a tour, we'll do the following:

```
var t = new Tour({
    backdrop: true,
    onShown: function(tour) {
        var stepElement = getTourElement(tour);
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-step-background'));
        $(stepElement).after($('.tour-backdrop'));
    }
});
 
function getTourElement(tour){
    return tour._steps[tour._current].element
}
```

This uses jQuery's [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) DOM manipulation to move the backdrop to the same stacking context as our tour object.

Also, we'll need to position both our tour backdrop elements as `fixed` instead of `absolute`, so they don't try to squeeze inside of our dialog.  We can do that with the following **CSS**:

```css
.tour-step-background, 
.tour-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
}
```

## [Working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DYNbj/)

Which should look like this:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for the research and very thorough explanation. I created an issue in GitHub (https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/166) in case someone else has come across this problem, but if no solution is found over the next few days I'll accept your answer.

Comment: updated answer should work much better than original

Comment: this is great, thank you! Unfortunately this causes some display issues in IE, as well as scrolling issues in all browsers due to the position: fixed, but it's a push in the right direction. Thanks again.

Comment: Confirmed this works with bootstrap-tour 0.9.3, but not 0.10.2.  We tried several things with 0.10.2 and just could not get it working as shown in this jsfiddle.

Comment: @Pete, see the [github issue above](https://github.com/sorich87/bootstrap-tour/issues/166) for a longer history of versioning issues.  Here's a [working demo in 10.1](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DYNbj/82/) which introduced some breaking changes.  [10.2 isn't on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-tour) yet, but I'm guessing that it will at least need some of the old fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem and I cheated by setting the opacity of tour-step-background to 0.4

Answer (score -2):

The right jsfiddle working with the last version of bootstrap tour

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DYNbj/82/][1]
```

Comment: Hi Harold, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)