# How to override CSS Z-Index Stacking Context with Transform?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the red square on top of the table. I read the articles about Z-index Stacking Context and this stack overflow [Override CSS Z-Index Stacking Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850037/override-css-z-index-stacking-context).
I guess there's a way to solve it using the transform stuff. But it's not working in my case. It would be helpful if you had some advice. Thanks.

[image]

- html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>
        <div><span class="red">Red</span></div>
        <div><span class="green">Green</span></div>
        <div><span class="blue">Blue</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- css

```css
.top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.bottom {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  z-index: 111;
  top: -40px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
}
.green {
  top: -20px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  top: -10px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
body,
div:first-child {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

- stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-8aygtn?file=styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can try this logic : i have modified the css , just added z-index at the last line of div :first-child.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <style>
    .top {
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
    .bottom {
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid #333;
      z-index: 4;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    thead,
    tfoot {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .red,
    .green,
    .blue {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100px;
      color: white;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .red {
      z-index: 111;
      top: -40px;
      left: 20px;
      background: red;
      transform: translateZ(1px);
    }
    .green {
      top: -20px;
      left: 60px;
      background: green;
    }
    .blue {
      top: -10px;
      left: 100px;
      background: blue;
    }
    body,
    div:first-child {
      z-index: -1;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>
        <div><span class="red">Red</span></div>
        <div><span class="green">Green</span></div>
        <div><span class="blue">Blue</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

m/Rxs7O.png

Comment: next line overrides the previous codes so, providing z-index to table tag again.

Comment: You should post the code, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
}
.bottom {
  position: relative;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  z-index: 1;
  top: -40px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;

}
.green {
  top: -20px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
  z-index: -3;
}
.blue {
  top: -10px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="top">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>The table body</td>
                <td>with two columns</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
           <div>
            <div><span class="red">Red</span></div>
            <div><span class="green">Green</span></div>
            <div><span class="blue">Blue</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Edited some of your code, z-index accepts negative numbers too, And removed the code:

```
body,
div:first-child {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3x746bc/1/

Comment: While it works, you really need to explain what you did and why. For now, you only make readers search for differences in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what you're after (I think) by commenting out some of your CSS. I didn't add anything new.

See the snippet below or check out [my fork of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-evj33n?file=styles.css).

```css
/* .top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
} */

.bottom {
  /* z-index: 1; */
  position: relative;
}
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
thead,
tfoot {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.red,
.green,
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.red {
  z-index: 111;
  top: -40px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  /* transform: translateZ(1px); */
}
.green {
  top: -20px;
  left: 60px;
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  top: -10px;
  left: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
/* body,
div:first-child {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>The table body</td>
            <td>with two columns</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>
        <div><span class="red">Red</span></div>
        <div><span class="green">Green</span></div>
        <div><span class="blue">Blue</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```